# Think somebody + adjective

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, contractions

Is this sentence from a movie grammatical?

> I thought you overqualified.

The construction "think someone adj." strikes me as odd. Explanations/examples?

Comment: @user3169 [corrected version of previously posted comment] It is in no way informal. It is rather more formal than the usual "thought (that) _noun_ was _adjective_."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed an accepted construction. It sounds a little more eloquent that the regular "thought that you/she/they was/were + adj.", so it will often be used in fine literature (or when the speaker is trying to emulate this "higher" style).

Examples of usage:

> — Do you think the earl really **thought him suitable** for someone's husband? ([source](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=hv8rDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT395&lpg=PT395&dq=%22thought+him+suitable%22&source=bl&ots=d5LCHKAKrd&sig=gRtINiDLFS-GwiSwycNhNYLowr8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwismp7OssPZAhWCkSwKHYjaC8oQ6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=%22thought%20him%20suitable%22&f=false))
>
> — Because of the way Robert spoke and carried himself, Matthew **thought him educated.** ([source](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=D1HHAgx7iVoC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=%22thought+him+educated%22&source=bl&ots=_Py9TZgEG3&sig=yop3-Q0r4bixgCw2znZRcx-Y37M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU0IaMs8PZAhWEKCwKHZZhAK4Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22thought%20him%20educated%22&f=false))
>
> — He was a decent, hardworking man and she **thought him well-adjusted.** ([source](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=yBtNBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=%22thought+him+well-adjusted%22&source=bl&ots=V1tn8UVqI-&sig=LrGCDEyMZJyiHmKclpjeHwQUsIk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYseGss8PZAhXFDCwKHXbxBqcQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22thought%20him%20well-adjusted%22&f=false))

It is similar to the construction where the verb is "to find". The following phrases will probably sound more familiar to you:

> to find somebody attractive/arrogant/ugly/well-mannered, etc., etc.

So it is used to express a certain opinion about a person.

Comment: It is indeed from a more literary context--a [film adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emma_(1996_theatrical_film)) of Jane Austin's Emma.